# Symfony 3 weird "choice" error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to build a checkbox list in Symfony 3.
This code:

```
    $choices = [
        'a' => 'fsssssss',
    ];

    $builder->add('memberships', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ]);
```

Returns the following error: **Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string** in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php (line 73)

If I add two more options, the error goes away and the field is shown correctly:

```
    $choices = [
        'a' => 'fsssssss',
        'd' => 'fsssssss',
        'g' => 'fsssssss',
    ];

    $builder->add('memberships', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ]);
```

Actually, there are many combinations that work and many that don't; I failed to see any pattern.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some sort of cache I need to clear?

Comment: try adding this to below `'multiple'=>false` : `'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
        return $key;
    },`

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: fsssssss is the key and not the value for your option, you need to change it

Comment: Change it with what? Are there better strings? :)

Comment: is memberships an orm related object ?   if so,   use EntityType

Comment: Thanks for the input. Using EntityType helped, thanks @SamJanssens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question:

If you use a form with the `data_class` option and a form field represents a property of an entity which should get selected by choices you can use `EntityType`:

```
    $builder->add('memberships', EntityType::class, [
        'class'     => MyClass::class,
        'choices'   => $choices,
        'expanded'  => true,
        'multiple'  => false
    ]);
```